# Changing title of my screen in an XML file

Tags: xml

I have already tried opening and closing the xml files again and again even closed the project but it also doesn't seem to work.
Where am I going wrong and what other alternatives do I have ?

[New Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALBQl.png)

Comment: have you used setTitle()?

Comment: I am new to development process and know only about doing it using the manifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity code you can use `setTilte("Title");`

like this:

**In onCreate()**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.setTitle("Title");
}
```

**In fragment**

```
 getActivity().stTitle("Title");
```

**Android.manifest file**

set `android:label="@string/title_of_activity"` , you have to do it for each activity by this way

for ex:

```
 <activity
 android:name="com.example.firstactivity"
 android:label="@string/title1"
 android:theme=.......

 <activity 
   android:name="com.example.secondactivity"
 android:label="@string/title2"
 android:theme=.......
```

Comment: Sir I just started learning Basix XML also I took along kotlin as my programming language and haven't learnt it to an extent where I can understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Sir it is showing an error I added another screenshot do have a look.

Comment: go to string.xml and put it there

Comment: **LIKE**   <string name="myprofilephoto">Myprofilephoto</string>

Comment: I have teamviewer